# Good Information about JEventDispatcher Class

Tags: joomla-api

Can anybody help me suggesting good sites/information describing about `JEventDispatcher` class in joomla.

> ***Register and Trigger of an Event??***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start is the doc page about how to use plugin events in your component: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_plugins_in_your_component

That should give you the basics.

There is another doc page which lists the available plugin events: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events
Yu can of course create and trigger your own events as well.